Buffer function and Projection
I've got a geopandas (EPSG:4326) that when I plot, this is the result (a road intersection):

What I'm trying to achieve is to "trim" these geometries around the center of the intersection. The resulting geopandas would be something like this:

Does anyone know how to achieve this using Python/Geopandas?

What is a geopandas ? It is a Python module, not a geometry

import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.read_file(r"C:\gistest\intersection.geojson")
orig_crs = df.crs
df = df.to_crs(df.estimate_utm_crs()) #Reproject the df to a crs with meters as units
ax = df.plot(figsize=(10,10), color="grey", zorder=1)

#Create a (red) point at the center of the intersection
center_coord = (59.1021107,14.1651579)
point = gpd.points_from_xy(x=[center_coord[1]], y=[center_coord[0]])[0]
point = gpd.GeoSeries(data=[point], crs=orig_crs).to_crs(df.crs)
point.plot(ax=ax, color="red")

#Buffer it and envelope the circle to create a blue square 
buffered = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[point.buffer(50).envelope.iloc[0]], crs=point.crs)
buffered.plot(ax=ax, color="blue", alpha=0.1)

#Rotate it (yellow)
buffered.geometry = buffered.rotate(angle=45)
buffered.plot(ax=ax, color="yellow", alpha=0.3)

#Intersect the rotated square with the road df
clipped = gpd.overlay(df1=df, df2=buffered, how="intersection")
clipped.plot(ax=ax, color="lime", linewidth=3)


